# Page number and name in the header of each page

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

How do you enter a page number on the right-hand side of each page?

Also, is there a command so that "My name" is on the top left corner of each page except the first page?

And maybe put a bar below the two above items?

I am using document class resume.

```
 \documentclass[margin,line]{resume}

 \begin{document}
 \name{\Large My name} 
 \begin{resume}

 This is page 1. 

 \newpage 


 This is page 2. 

 \newpage 

 This is page 3.   

 \end{resume}
 \end{document}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Suggestion: `fancyhdr` package. [fancyhdr package](ftp://www.ctan.org/pub/tex-archive/macros/latex2e/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf)

Comment: @azetina please turn your comment into an answer, with a complete MWE :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fancyhdr` works with `resume` (which is based on `article`), but some adjustments are necessary:

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{resume}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % to provide mock text

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\makeatletter
\fancyhead[L]{\textbf{\expandafter\@gobble\@name}}
\makeatother
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyheadoffset[L]{\sectionwidth}
\setlength\headheight{12pt}
\setlength\headsep{3pt}
\addtolength\topmargin{-15pt}
\AtBeginDocument{\thispagestyle{empty}}


\begin{document}

\name{\Large My name}

\begin{resume}

\kant

\end{resume}

\end{document}
```

Comment out the `\fancyheadoffset` line if you don't want that the line on the pages following page 1 are extended on the left. If you want to increase the separation between the rule and the text, modify the value of `\headsep` and also the value of `\topmargin`.

[image]

Note. The mysterious `\expandafter\@gobble\@name` is needed because `\@name` expands to `\Large My Name`, after `\name{My Name}`, so we have to remove the unwanted `\Large` command.

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful, but since I do not have kantlipsum.sty, I followed the instructions as on this link: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/kantlipsum and downloaded kantlipsum.sty, kantlipsum.dtx, kantlipsum.ins. But neither the name in the header or the page numbers are showing up on my pdf file. Am I at a trust-worthy website and am supposed to download the kantlipsum package from this link?

Answer (score 5):

The following code may be of assistance to solve your issue:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Used to create the random paragraphs
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{My Name} % controls the left corner of the header
\chead{} % controls the center of the header
\rhead{} % controls the right corner of the header
\lfoot{} % controls the left corner of the footer
\cfoot{} % controls the center of the footer
\rfoot{Page~\thepage} % controls the right corner of the footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}% Removes the header from the first page. Change plain to empty to remove the numbering entirely.
\lipsum[2-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you try and mould the answer into a `resume` document class? There *may* be specific requirements dealing with something other than `article`.

Comment: Sure, but what type of class is `resume`?

Comment: Based on the document class options (`[margin,line]`) and only using `\name`, it could be a renamed version of the [`res`](http://ctan.org/pkg/res) class.